# elasticsearch searching array field inside nested type

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to filter my result using nested filter but i am getting incorrect result

here is my mapping info

```
{
  "stock" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "clip" : {
        "properties" : {
          "description" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "keywords" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "category" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "tags" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index_name" : "tag"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index_name" : "tag"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

clip document data

```
{
      "_index" : "stock",
      "_type" : "clip",
      "_id" : "AUnsTOBBpafrKleQN284",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{
   "title": "journey to forest",
   "description": "this clip contain information about the animals",
   "tags": ["birls", "wild", "animals", "roar", "forest"],
   "keywords": [
          {
             "tags": ["spring","summer","autumn"],
             "category": "Weather"
          },
          {
             "tags": ["Cloudy","Stormy"],
             "category": "Season"
          },
          {
             "tags": ["Exterior","Interior"],
             "category": "Setting"
          }
       ]
  }
```

i am trying to filter tags inside nested field 'keywords'
here is my query

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
             "nested": {
                 "path": "keywords",
                     "filter": {
                         "bool": {
                             "must": [
                                 {
                                    "terms": { "tags": ["autumn", "summer"] }
                                 }
                         ]
                     }
                 }
             }

         }
      }
   }
}
```

i am getting no result why ?
what's wrong with my query or schema please help

Answer (score 1):

The above query is syntactically incorrect . You need to provide the full path to ***tags*** from root **keywords** in the term query i.e.***keywords.tags***

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
             "nested": {
                 "path": "keywords",
                     "filter": {
                         "bool": {
                             "must": [
                                 {
                                    "terms": { "keywords.tags": ["autumn", "summer"] }
                                 }
                         ]
                     }
                 }
             }

         }
      }
   }
}
```